# After registration, store email address and redirect to to another page

Tags: redirection

I have this code working:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
switch ($form_id) {
case 'user_register_form':
      $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_register_submit';
  break;
}
}

function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$form_state['redirect'] = 'content/welcome';
}
```

This is working great no problems.

The node I'm redirecting to has a typical welcome message.  Part of the message has:  Your verification has been sent to (user's email address).

How do I get the registration email address for the welcome message?

I've created a custom template for the content/welcome node.  Just not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your submit handler, you could use `drupal_set_message` to set the message like this:

```
function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'content/welcome';
  drupal_set_message('Your mail is @mail', array('@mail' => $form_state['user']->mail));
}
```

You could also save it in the `$_SESSION` if you don't want to use drupal_set_message and get it from there.

Comment: Thanks!  That got me on the right direction.  I ended up adding the variable to the session:
`code function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $_SESSION['var1'] = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    $var1 = $form_state['values']['mail'];
       //this works
       dpm($var1);
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'content/welcome';
    }`